# PHP installing \ building

Tags: php, centos, version, centos6

I've followed this guide: http://www.phamviet.net/2012/06/03/centos-6-2-compile-php-5-4-2-from-source/

It all works as it should, but when I'm done and I type 'service httpd restart' following by 'php --version', it still displays the old 5.1.6 PHP version.

This is 'uname -a' : Linux xxxxxx.com 2.6.32-042stab061.2 #1 SMP Fri Aug 24 09:07:21 MSK 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

It's a VPS hosted in my main dedicated server (OpenVZ).

Not sure what else to say, but I appreciate any help :)

OS: CentOS 6

Comment: Are you sure it isn't still the same binary? Although, I'd suggest you install any new/unstable packages with the package manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remove old version of the php? `sudo yum remove php` or (php5, I don't remember how excatly the package is named)

After removing run `sudo updatedb` and `sudo locate php` and delete any leftovers (e.g /etc/php, /usr/local/php and so on). Care not to delete files from other applications or the package manager. When your system is clean and no traces of the old version are there install the new version: after the config step that finishes the guide run `make` and then `sudo make install`